Difference between CAST and TRUNC
I came across lot of SQL problems when their is timestamp given
Most of my queries I use CAST. I would like to know the difference between the CAST and TRUNC
In which scenario when to use what ?

CAST changes the data type of a parameter value. TRUNC removes a fractional part from a numeric or DATE value. Do you have some samples?

@Wernfried Domscheit  : Can you create some sample and explain me

@KenWhite The problem is for people coming from other SQL dialects where a DATE does not have a time component and then CAST(timestamp_value AS DATE) and TRUNC(timestamp_value, 'DD') may be used interchangably if you want to GROUP BY days. In Oracle, a DATE also has a time component so they are not identical (but that is because Oracle's implementation of DATE pre-dates the ANSI specification for a date and Oracle has kept backwards compatibility with its earliest versions).


CAST is used to change from one data-type to another.
TRUNC is used to truncate a number or a DATE or TIMESTAMP data-type to a given precision.


Assuming, since you are mentioning TIMESTAMP, that you are focusing on date-time data-types.
What is a DATE and a TIMESTAMP?
Before understanding what CAST and TRUNC do it is necessary to understand what a DATE and a TIMESTAMP actually are.
A DATE is a binary data-type that consists of:

7 bytes representing century, year-of-century, month, day, hours, minutes and seconds.

A TIMESTAMP is a binary data-type that consists of:

7 bytes representing century, year-of-century, month, day, hours, minutes and seconds;
0-6 optional bytes representing fractional seconds; and
If it has a time zone component then 7 bytes representing the time zone.

Both DATE and TIMESTAMP ALWAYS have those initial 7-bytes and a TIMESTAMP may have up to 20 bytes of data.

CAST
When you use CAST(timestamp_value AS DATE) you are asking Oracle to create a 7-byte binary object from the first 7 (mandatory) bytes from the TIMESTAMP object.
So:
CAST(TIMESTAMP '2001-02-03 04:05:06.007 UTC' AS DATE)

Will result in a DATE with the value 2001-02-03 04:05:06 (discarding the fractional seconds and the UTC time zone).

TRUNC
The TRUNC function has the signature TRUNC(date_or_timestamp_value, format_model) and returns a DATE data-type with the binary components that are more precise than format_model argument set to the minimum value (0 for time components and 1 for month and day).
So:
TRUNC(TIMESTAMP '2001-02-03 04:05:06.007 UTC', 'DD')

Will result in a DATE with the value 2001-02-03 00:00:00 (discarding the fractional seconds and the UTC time zone and setting the components more precise than the days - so hours, minutes and seconds - to 0).
and
TRUNC(TIMESTAMP '2001-02-03 04:05:06.007 UTC', 'YY')

Will result in a DATE with the value 2001-01-01 00:00:00 (discarding the fractional seconds and the UTC time zone and setting the components more precise than the years to the minimum - so hours, minutes and seconds to 0 and days and months to 1).


In which scenario when to use what?

If you want to GROUP BY days then you do NOT want to use CAST because it does not remove the time component when you CAST(timestamp_value AS DATE). Instead you want to use TRUNC(timestamp_value, 'DD') - you will still have a time component but all values on that day will have a time of midnight so they will all be grouped together.
If you want to convert a TIMESTAMP to DATE without changing the hours, minutes or seconds components then use CAST - usually this is done so you can subtract to DATEs and get the difference as a numeric value representing the number of days (or fractions thereof); if you were to subtract TIMESTAMPs then you would get an INTERVAL DAY TO SECOND instead of a number.
